# Remove/reset CSS behavior property

Tags: css, internet-explorer, behavior, html-components

Is it possible to remove the IE-specific behavior CSS property via a more specific rule or the `!important` declaration? Example:

```
.a-rule
{
  behavior: url(/some.htc);
}
.a-rule.more-specific
{
  behavior: /*no HTC*/
}
```

I realize that overriding CSS properties is undesirable, but I'm stuck here.

**On Edit**: I'm not sure where people are getting confused about this question. For all purposes, you can consider this already being an IE specific stylesheet. I'm asking how, if `.a-rule` above exists and is immutable, how can one remove the behavior via a more specific rule? A standard CSS equivalent would be:

```
.a-rule
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.a-rule.more-specific
{
  border: 0 none;
}
```

One can reset the border property for a subset of elements via a more specific rule. I'm asking how to reset the behavior property in an analogous way.

Comment: It makes no sense to mark this as a duplicate. It pre-dates the other question, has more detail, and more people involved.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The default value is "none". See:

[What is the *correct* way to unset the behavior property in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953447/what-is-the-correct-way-to-unset-the-behavior-property-in-css)

The solution:

```
.a-rule
{
  behavior: url(/some.htc);
}
.a-rule.more-specific
{
  behavior: none;
}
```

Comment: I found an empty string worked as well (at least in IE8), but it looks like the default value is actually `none`, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953447/what-is-the-correct-way-to-unset-the-behavior-property-in-css I'm sorry the answers you got were so bad.

Comment: nice solution, doesn't seem to work for color though, does anyone have any solutions for that use case?

Comment: A "none" color doesn't really make sense. Would it be black? White? Transparent?

Comment: It's 'transparent' if you are trying to change background-color.

Answer (score -5):

```
.a_rule {
  border: 1px solid black; /* we know border is black */
  behavior: url(/some.htc) /* we know something happen inside some.htc */
}
 .a_rule.more-specific {
  border: 0 none; /* we remove the border */
  behavior: url(/some.htc) /* we remove something inside some.htc */
}
```

use different `.htc` file

Answer (score -8):

Maybe use conditional tags for IE in your head

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
    .a-rule {
       behavior: url(/some.htc);
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: There is no such syntax in stylesheets.