# What is the *correct* way to unset the behavior property in CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm wondering what the correct way to reset/unset the CSS `behavior` property is for IE.

```
div { behavior:url(fixIE.htc); }
```

I need to reset this for some specific elements. I started searching for the answer after I noticed that this *does not work*:

```
.my-div { behavior:0; }
```

I found [an SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513738/remove-reset-css-behavior-property/4513868) that says an empty string worked, but there's no reference cited that this is in fact the correct way to do it:

```
.my-div { behavior:''; }
```

However, I've seen this used in some code I've come across:

```
.my-div { behavior:none; }
```

I cannot find any actual reference as it's not really in the spec, the closest thing I found was here:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/behavior

...but it doesn't clarify the issue.

Which way is correct, or does it not matter (consider javascript interaction as well, if it makes any difference)? Please include a reference if it exists - that's what I'm really looking for.

Comment: Wow, I don't miss these days... IE6... IE7... IE8... htc files, float bugs, flash players, table based layouts...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can check it at the w3c documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-becss-19990804#behavior). As it says, the initial value is `none`.

Comment: Aha, that's what I was looking for. I knew `''` didn't seem right and I couldn't find anything from the W3C, or anything official about it, I assumed because it was an MSIE thing... Umm, it *is* IE-only right?

Comment: IE and Netscape, using something called _Action Sheets_ I think, so, yes, IE-only in practice :)

Comment: Indeed, not even the current version of the draft scumah linked has a behavior property.

Comment: What's misleading is that `unset` works in most browsers but then breaks in IE. Here I was chasing what I thought to be an SVG scaling problem with IE. Then I noticed no checkbox appears in IE's dev tools to toggle `unset` and got suspicious... Now using `max-width: none` and it's displaying at the expected size. I realize your answer is regarding `behavior`, but it seems this pattern applies in many situations.

Answer (score -7):

I think the answer to this question lies in the question itself, just set the behavior to `unset` value:

```
.my-div { behavior: unset; }
```

Tested on Firefox, hope that helps.

Comment: `unset` is an invalid keyword in IE.