# how disable bahavior(pie.htc) for IE7 and lower

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I used bahavior(pie.htc) in main css for IE8 nut i want do not work for IE7 and lower versions.
i have ie7.css and this style in it:

```
#wrapper * {behavior:none}
```

but is not disable all of behavior in main.css.
is there any solution?

Comment: My quesion is how apply {behavior:none} to all elements and class in main.css with ie7.css

Answer (score 2):

wrap the call to the behavior to be called only when greater than ie7

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
<style>
      behavior: url(PIE.htc);
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

**edit**: the behavior:none part is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513738/remove-reset-css-behavior-property%20) with more reference

but anyway you should insert it in a conditional comment

Comment: IE 7 use main.css but i want disable behavior in ie7.css

Comment: i nead som css like #wrapper * {behavior:none} to disable all elements and classes in main.css

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach, anyway I don't know any behavior:none

Answer (score 1):

You should take a different approach here. Instead of trying to "cancel" the behavior you already applied, why not just use it only in browsers where you need it? Wich means taking it out of your main.css file and only using it like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style>
    Here goes all your behavior calls :

    some_selector {
      behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

That way you won't need to overwrite them anywhere else, they will only be applied in IE 8.